# How to make registration form ajax?

Tags: ajax, user-registration

I have a registration form and I would like to make it ajax, is there such plugin or how can I adjust the standard wordpress registration page to be ajax without reloading page. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Login With Ajax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/login-with-ajax/)** is a very actively developed plugin that enables AJAX Login / Registration without refreshing your screen. It has a number of other features as well, take a look.